# How to generate download link from any Youtube videos in PHP?

Tags: php, youtube

I'm working on a web application that allow users to post any Youtube videos to their profile or pages they manages. This is the code that I use to post Youtube video to my profile

```
 $videoUpload = $fb->post('/me/videos', ['description' => 'example description', 'file_url' => 'https://r2---sn-npoeene7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?pl=24&lmt=1513082002389285&id=o-AIPnl4v8svvYBTFPYwJOsRanE_5O8YSK0F3bMkTqN6QR&itag=22&signature=8051FCC4C243296224CD1D7ADB4E5C0A90125C57.66FF9FF2063C3A8F00F143FB51BB3E98F7AEBB7B&requiressl=yes&ip=203.189.156.104&sparams=dur,ei,expire,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source&key=cms1&mime=video%2Fmp4&dur=301.952&fvip=2&ipbits=0&c=WEB&expire=1519648901&ratebypass=yes&ei=JayTWtSaDcWqoQORionoCg&source=youtube&redirect_counter=1&cm2rm=sn-jvbxuxavoapox-2oil7e&fexp=23712580&req_id=21384f45d53ba3ee&cms_redirect=yes&mm=29&mn=sn-npoeene7&ms=rdu&mt=1519627218&mv=m'], $access_token);
 $videoUpload = $videoUpload->getGraphNode()->asArray();
```

The problem is that Facebook not allow to post Youtube link directly, so I need to generate a downloadable link from that video in order to post to Facebook.
Here is the PHP code that use to generate a download link from a Youtube video

```
   <?php

$id = 'RllJtOw0USI'; 

if (isset($_GET["id"]))
    $id = $_GET["id"];

parse_str(file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$id), $video_data);

$streams = $video_data['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];
$streams = explode(',',$streams);
$counter = 1;

foreach ($streams as $streamdata) {
    printf("Stream %d:<br/>----------------<br/><br/>", $counter);
    
    parse_str($streamdata,$streamdata);

    foreach ($streamdata as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "url") {
            $value = urldecode($value);
            printf("<strong>%s:</strong> <a href='%s'>video link</a><br/>", $key, $value);
        } else {
            printf("<strong>%s:</strong> %s<br/>", $key, $value);
        }
    }

    $counter = $counter+1;
    printf("<br/><br/>");
}

?>
```

It's only work with **RllJtOw0USI** if I change the **$id** to **dMK_npDG12Q** it's not working anymore, and I got the errors as follow:

```
status=fail&errorcode=150&errordetail=0&reason=This+video+contains+content+from+Vevo.+It+is+restricted+from+playback+on+certain+sites+or+applications.%0A%3Ca+href%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DdMK_npDG12Q%26feature%3Dplayer_embedded%27+target%3D%27_blank%27%3EWatch+on+YouTube%3C%2Fa%3E
```

How can I get the link from this kind of video?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at reason in json, you can see that

```
This video contains content from Vevo. It is restricted from playback on certain sites or applications
```

So you should obey their restrictions, or find any other link which is not restricted yet.

Comment: So mean we have no way to generate link from that kind of video right?

Comment: Actually some workarounds might exist, i don't know exact way to do it.

Comment: I cannot find a solution please  help

Comment: Did you look for same video on other video sites like vimeo?

Comment: No. I create this app for users use and they mostly get from youtube only

Comment: It seems like there is no way to do it according to error message, sorry.

Comment: But why IDM can download all kind of videos, it can generate download link from all kind of youtube videos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165941/discussion-between-yilmaz-and-doo-doo).